# Difference between "enterprise application" and "app registration" in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Could someone please tell me what the difference is between "enterprise application" and  "app registration" in Azure.

Appreciate if you could give me an example & why some application cannot be registered under blade "Enterprise application" and vise versa.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cde6dfc0-ba30-4cd7-8b0a-7420afb3bcff/difference-between-azure-ad-app-registration-and-enterprise-application

Answer (score 146, accepted):

An **App Registration** is a way of reserving your app and URL with Azure AD, allowing it to communicate with Azure AD, hooking up your reply urls, and enabling AAD services on it. When you have an application that you are developing and want to integrate with Azure, you need to register your application in App Registrations, where you will configure your reply URL, logout URL, and API access if needed. When you register your application, Azure AD assigns a unique Application ID to it and allows you to add certain capabilities such as credentials, permissions, and sign-ons. The default settings allow only users from the tenant under which your app is registered to sign into your application.

The Enterprise Applications blade might be confused with App Registrations because the Enterprise Application blade contains the list of your service principals. However, the term **Enterprise App** generally refers to applications published by other companies in the AAD gallery that can be used within your organization. For example, if you want to integrate [Facebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/workplacebyfacebook-tutorial) and manage SSO within your organization, you can integrate it from the Enterprise Applications dropdown in the applications blade. **Your own applications** will *also* be represented in the Enterprise Applications blade as Service Principals, which are instantiations of your applications in the tenant.

App Registration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-add-azure-ad-app

Integrating an Enterprise application (G-Suite): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-tutorial

Comment: could i have 2 enterprise apps (instances) of a single registration?

Comment: @ChrisDaMour: Yes, you can have multiple instances of the same enterprise app. For example, ServiceNow Dev and ServiceNow Prod, both pointing to different ServiceNow instances

Comment: So... if I'm setting up inter-app authorisation between two services, using a service principal within the same _subscription_, is an Enterprise App necessary in this scenario? Will it be created regardless? I'm specifically talking about granting DataBricks access to ADLS Gen2.

Comment: @Marilee - There is also an option to do a registration under 'Enterprise applications' by clicking "New application".
This will also create an entry under 'App registrations'
Could you please help me understand when should I create new application by clicking "New application" under Enterprise applications?

Comment: Looks like @Marilee expanded this answer into a [blog post](https://marileeturscak.com/posts/app-registrations-enterprise-applications-service-principals/)

Comment: This is one of many things in Azure that make it seem more like a misguided final project for someone's undergrad CS degree than a complete and well-designed product produced by one of the wealthiest and most powerful talent companies in the world

Comment: @JonathonAnderson ...and then they decided renaming everything to "Azure Entra ID" and change terminology and docs location all over the place 

Answer (score 80):

This is, I agree, potentially confusing to a new-to-AAD developer or administrator.  [Nitin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59966843/199172) does a good job of summarizing this but I wanted to add an answer with documentation references.

At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals it says:

> The application object is the *global* representation of your
> application for use across all tenants, and the service principal is
> the *local* representation for use in a specific tenant.

Then, at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-how-applications-are-added, it says:

> You can manage [application objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals#application-object) in the Azure portal through the
> [App Registrations](https://aka.ms/appregistrations) experience.
> Application objects describe the application
> to Azure AD and can be considered the definition of the application,
> allowing the service to know how to issue tokens to the application
> based on its settings.

and

> You can manage [service principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals#service-principal-object) in the Azure portal through the
> [Enterprise Applications](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/StartboardApplicationsMenuBlade/AllApps/menuId/) experience. Service principals are what govern
> an application connecting to Azure AD and can be considered the
> instance of the application in your directory. For any given
> application, it can have at most one application object (which is
> registered in a "home" directory) and one or more service principal
> objects representing instances of the application in every directory
> in which it acts.

So, for third-party apps, you'll only have a service principal in **Enterprise applications**.  For first-party apps that are internal, you'll have something in both places - one to define the app (**App registrations**) and one to allow the app to actually sign in to Azure AD (**Enterprise applications**).  When you define the first-party app in the App registrations, you'll also automatically create an entry in Enterprise apps.  If you look at the two entries, you'll see that the **Application ID** links the two together.

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 42):

Shorter way to understand is...
App Registration are basically the apps local to the tenant/organization in which they have been registered to generate unique application id.
Enterprise apps blade shows global apps (belonging to other tenants) which can be configured and used within your tenant/organization.

The workflow is you create the App Registration (Application) in your tenant, which also creates the Enterprise Application (Service principal) in your tenant. Then when another tenant user wants to login to your app, they grant your app the permissions it requires and the Enterprise Application (Service Principal) is created in their tenant. This effectively mirrors your application in their tenant.

Answer (score 14):

Well, there're some good answers here but they are too verbose so I feel the simplest thing is show three pictures and one statement:

1. In the **App Registration**, we have "*Application Objects*":
   [image]
2. To understand what you're seeing in the **Enterprise Applications** blade are "*Service Principals*":
   [image]
3. And this is the relationship between the two in a multi-tenant example:

Adatum - The tenant used by the company that *developed* **the HR app**

Contoso - The tenant used by the Contoso organization, which is a *consumer* of the **HR app**

Fabrikam - The tenant used by the Fabrikam organization, which also *consumes* the **HR app**

[image]

[image]

And with that out of the way, we can understand this statement:

> Similar to a class in object-oriented programming, the application
> object has some static properties that are applied to all the created
> service principals (or application instances).
> The application object is the *global* representation of your
> application for use across all tenants, and the service principal is
> the *local* representation for use in a specific tenant. **The application
> object serves as the template from which common and default properties
> are derived for use in creating corresponding service principal
> objects.**

Also said in a different way:

> Application objects - Although there are exceptions, application
> objects can be considered the definition of an application.

> Service  principals - Can be considered an instance of an application. Service
> principals generally reference an application object, and one
> application object can be referenced by multiple service principals
> across directories.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals

Answer (score 11):

Additionally, within Application registration you can configure OpenId-Connect (OpenID/OAuth) based authentication. Within Enterprise Apps you can configure SAML based auth

Comment: Technically correct, but off-topic and not answering the question.

Comment: this is actually kind of of important aspect to understand the different between application registration and enterprise app. Application Registration/OAuth2 allow the app to delegate to user identity for resource access, whereas the Enterprise application is application Identity(a service principle)

Comment: Let's not be pedantic... by starting their answer with 'Additionally' it shows that they are adding additional, related information, off topic or not isn't relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Simple put:
Application Registration create an global application object which will allow the app to delegate to user identity for resource access, whereas the Enterprise application is the application identity(a service principle) in each AD tenant

Answer (score -1):

Good answers. App registration is like opening up a pizza shop. There is only 1 instance of it. The attributes of a pizza shop are different and done in this specific blade. Enterprise application - a misleading term, is more like the customers who buy the pizza. There can be 1 or more consumers of the pizza. The attributes of a consumer are different, and these service principals/consumers, are done in the enterprise application blade.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).